# Faster Way to Create a Subset within a Loop or Apply Function in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so apologies in advance for bad form in my code.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go through a dataframe, row by row, and modify a value based on logic that references other columns within that row  or an entirely different dataframe. The issue is that the logic I'm using necessitates creating and subsetting a dataframe for each row to retrieve a minimum value. My real data set is 47000 rows and 15 columns, so creating 47,000 subsets is taking a long time.

Here are sample datasets to help describe what I'm talking about.

```
df1 <- data.frame('A' = c(rep("Beer", 2), rep("Chip", 2)), 'B' = c(NA, 3,
       NA,9), 'C' = 5:8, 'D' = NA)
df2 <- data.frame('Q' = c(rep("Beer", 2), rep("Chip", 2)), 'R' = 6:9, 'S' = 
       c(12, 15, 4, 18), 'T' = c(23, 45, 75, 34))
```

df1:

```
  A    B    C    D
 Beer  NA   5    NA
 Beer  3    6    NA
 Chip  NA   7    NA
 Chip  9    8    NA
```

df2:

```
  Q    R    S    T
 Beer  6    12    23
 Beer  7    15    45
 Chip  8    4     75
 Chip  9    18    34
```

This loop does what I want, namely checking whether a value is NA in column B or not, if it isn't then use that value in for column D, if it is NA then retrieve the minimum value from a filtered subset of df2. In the real use case I have other filtering conditions.

```
require(dplyr)

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  if (!(is.na(df1$B[i]))) {
    df1$D[i] <- df1$B[i]}
  else {x <- filter(df2,  df1$A[i] == df2$Q)
      x <- min(x$S)
      df1$D[i] <- x
  }
}
```

Everyone says to avoid loops in R, so I created this function using apply which also works (although is a little more difficult to follow):

```
FUNC <- function(x) {
  apply(x, 1, function(y) {
    if (!(is.na(y[2]))) {
      y[4] <- y[2]}
    else {z <- filter(df2,  y[1] == df2$Q)
    z <- min(z$S)
    y[4] <- z}
  }
  )
}

df1$D <- as.numeric(FUNC(df1))
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D
    Beer  NA   5    12
    Beer  3    6    3
    Chip  NA   7    4
    Chip  9    8    9
```

Aside question: is there a way to reference items in vector `y` by name instead of by index position?

So is there a better way to do this?  Right now both methods take about 5-8 minutes to run through 47,000+ rows which seems long to me.

Comment: yes you should be able to improve this... having things in 2 different data.frames may hinder things a little. any reason for this?

Comment: This is an intermediary step in a bigger process of doing database joins using sqldf. There may be a better way of bringing this value in at an earlier stage in the process, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1$D <- df2 %>% 
  rename(A=Q) %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(D=min(S)) %>% 
  right_join(df1, by="A") %>% 
  mutate(D=ifelse(is.na(B), D.x, B)) %>% 
  `[[`("D")
```